# jquery balloon not showing with .showBalloon()

Tags: jquery, popup, tooltip, balloon

I'm trying to have the balloon from the balloon plugin show up on document ready but for some reason the .showballoon method isn't doing anything. I would think it would be as easy as this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bordercolor;

    $(".editDisplay").balloon({
        contents: "Required",
        position: "right",
        offsetX: -20,
        css: {
            border: 'solid 1px red',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(239, 177, 177)',
            color: '#000',
            display: 'block'
        }
    });

    $('.editDisplay').showBalloon();
}
```

but it's not showing up, it only shows up on hover. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example in their docs they do this. You might lose the hover though.

```
$(".editDisplay").showBalloon({
    contents: "Required",
    position: "right",
    offsetX: -20,
    css: {
        border: 'solid 1px red',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(239, 177, 177)',
        color: '#000',
        display: 'block'
    }
});
```

Comment: yea this doesn't do much difference, i'm afraid i might have to use something else in order to achieve what i want

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of messing around with it's parameters, so instead i looked at the markup and just added classes to it that I can display or not display, the code:

```
<div class='editDisplay'>
<div class='requiredBalloon'>
Required
<div class='requiredBalloonArrow1'></div><div class='requiredBalloonArrow2'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
.editDisplay {
    position: relative;
}

.requiredBalloon {
    min-width: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: rgb(85, 85, 85) 4px 4px 4px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.85;
    z-index: 32767;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(239, 177, 177);
    right: -50px;
    top: -4px;
}

.requiredBalloonArrow1, .requiredBalloonArrow2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

.requiredBalloonArrow1 {
    border-width: 7px 12px 7px 0px;
    border-color: transparent rgb(255, 0, 0) transparent transparent;
    left: -12px;
    top: 6.5px;
}

.requiredBalloonArrow2 {
    border-width: 6px 10px 6px 0px;
    border-color: transparent rgb(239, 177, 177) transparent transparent;
    left: -10px;
    top: 7.5px;
}
```

and then using jquery i chose to display or not display, or hover if this is what u want:

```
$(this).parent().find(".requiredBalloon").css("display", "block");
```

hope this helps anyone,

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, the $("selector") returned multiple elements (some of them are not visible).
When I refine the selector, it started to work.
You can check if this is the case by running from the console:

```
$("selector").length
```

You should expected for 1.